# How to read a text file into command line history

Tags: windows-10, windows-console

I have a .txt file with command line commands on each line. How can I load the contents of this text file back into the "clipboard" or "history" memory of a command prompt session and be able to arrow key up/down through them?

**Example of commands and format inside blah.txt:**

```
ipconfig
ipconfig /flushdns
cd C:\blah
```

Comment: The console maintains a separate history buffer for each executable that's attached to it -- up to the number of history buffers configured in the console properties. There is no console function to modify the history buffer for a given client executable (e.g. cmd.exe, powershell.exe, python.exe, etc). Even the functions to read it are undocumented and only made available via doskey.exe.

Comment: This is more an OS question than a programming question. It's probably more suitable for [su]. With that being said, open a command prompt and  type `doskey /?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jonathan

I'm not currently a Windows user, but it looks like this could solve your problem. You'll have to add commands via .csv or .xml, not .txt file though.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/add-history

Hope this helps.

Comment: PowerShell bypasses the Windows console input history, so this will work if the op is only concerned with input history for PowerShell. It won't work to set the command history for other console shells -- such as cmd.exe, diskpart.exe, netsh.exe, or python.exe -- which use history buffers allocated in the console itself.

Comment: I'm upvoting anyway because it's probably good enough for a lot of people, since PowerShell is gaining popularity.

Comment: Thanks @eryksun for clarifying this solution only works within Powershell input history.

Comment: Although this is a solution for powershell only, it will work for the problem I was solving. Thank you!